# Select the highest value of column 2 per column 1

Tags: sql, oracle19c

Given the following table **P_PROV**

```
+----+-----------+-----------+
| id | date      | person_id |
+----+-----------+-----------+
| 1  |19/06/2019 | 1         |
| 2  |18/07/2010 | 2         |
| 3  |19/06/2020 | 1         |
| 4  |17/06/2020 | 2         |
| 5  |28/06/2020 | 3         |
+----+-----------+-----------+
```

I want this output

```
+----+-----------+-----------+
| id | date      | person_id |
+----+-----------+-----------+
| 3  |19/06/2020 | 1         |
| 4  |17/06/2020 | 2         |
| 5  |28/06/2020 | 3         |
+----+-----------+-----------+
```

Putting this in words, I want to return per person the maximum date. I tried something like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT pp.date, pp.id FROM P_PROV pp
            WHERE (SELECT MAX(aa.date) 
            FROM P_PROV aa) = pp.date;
```

This one is only returning one row (of course, because the MAX will return the maximum date only), but I really don't know how to approach this issue, any kind of help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ROW_NUMBER` provides one way to handle this:

```
SELECT id, date, person_id
FROM
(
    SELECT t.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY person_id ORDER BY date DESC) rn
    FROM yourTable t
) t
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Oracle has a fun way to do this using aggregation:

```
select max(id) keep (dense_rank first order by date desc) as id,
       max(date) as date, person_id
from P_PROV
group by person_id;
```

Given that your ids are increasing, this probably also does what you want:

```
select max(id) as id, max(date) as date, person_id
from P_PROV
group by person_id;
```